# Does firebase ab testing support server side

Tags: firebase-ab-testing

Have a requirement where we need to send push notification to users based on some A/B test. So different users will receive different content and we hope to reuse the existing firebase A/B testing framework we already have. 
How can this be done? 
Only way I can think of is for our client/app to get remote config when launched and submit it somewhere to our server. 
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebaser here!

Unfortunately Firebase ABT does not support this use case at the moment.